# Python remove duplicate entries from list within a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Suppose I have,

```
a = [['abcTable : [os : set1] [origin : tag1] [os_version : p7] [0000_id : 1234567890] [cust : 75sa] [model : what-ra-ffff] [manufacturer : what] '],
     ['abcTable : [os : set1] [origin : tag2] [os_version : p8] [0000_id : unknown] [cust : 75sa] [model : tt_xy2U] [manufacturer : what] '], 
     ['abcTable : [os : set1] [origin : tag1] [os_version : p7] [0000_id : 1234567890] [cust : 75sa] [model : what-ra-ffff] [manufacturer : what] '],
     ['abcTable : [os : set1] [origin : tag2] [os_version : p8] [0000_id : unknown] [cust : 75sa] [model : tt_xy2U] [manufacturer : what] ']]
```

Notice that `a_0` and `a_2` are equivalent and `a_1` and `a_3` are equivalent. How can I go about returning the same list but with the duplicated removed?

I have tried everything from enumeration and list comprehension, but have not come up with anything successful. I think it is because it is a list inside a list.

Comment: Please post what you have tried & how it was deficient.

Comment: I assume you mean `a[0]` and `a[2]`? Can you ensure that the format of your code is correct? Is each element really a single string? I doubt it

Comment: a[0] and a[2] are not the same, their `0000_id` fields differ. Same with 1 and 3

Comment: To be honest, I've deleted everything I've tried. And yes a[0] etc. Format of list is exactly as it should be.

Comment: Oh, just realized that. let me fix that!

Comment: This looks a lot like JSON data, are you nesting it like this yourself or is it coming to you as JSON? because that would make it much easier to work with

Comment: ok updated. Not JSON, and this is exactly as it comes. Having a difficult time sorting it out.

Comment: and the objective is to deduplicate by id correct?

Comment: Does `list(set(i[0] for i in a))` solve your problem?

Comment: essentially I need [a[0], a[2]], since a[1] and a[3] are duplicates.

Comment: yes @rahlf23!!!. thank you

Comment: To be clear: This is a list of lists of strings. You are trying to use substrings to deduplicate.

Comment: ahh. yes I should have clarified this. thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove duplicates, then you can use `set()` and convert back to a `list`:

```
list(set(i[0] for i in a))
```

Returns:

```
['abcTable : [os : set1] [origin : tag1] [os_version : p7] [0000_id : 1234567890] [cust : 75sa] [model : what-ra-ffff] [manufacturer : what] ',
'abcTable : [os : set1] [origin : tag2] [os_version : p8] [0000_id : unknown] [cust : 75sa] [model : tt_xy2U] [manufacturer : what] ']
```

Comment: It's worth noting this de-lists the inner elements. This may be a feature or a bug depending on your usage.

Comment: A good nuance to be aware of, thanks for the comment @TemporalWolf

Comment: I spoke too soon. Not working as I needed...It is changing the order, but it is not removing them. It is working for the example I provided, however if the list is larger and the elements differ, it is not deleting duplicates throughout the list.

Comment: Then you need to provide the example you have for which it is not working. Otherwise, we have no way to know what your issue is.

Comment: nvm, my mistake.